# web2py RESTful service

Tags: web-services, http, rest, web2py

I'm trying to implement a RESTful service as explained here:
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1533/restful-api-with-web2py

GET, PUT and POST work as expected, but DELETE doesnt. I get

```
 <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> not indexable

web2py™ Version 
 2.6.3-stable+timestamp.2013.09.15.17.01.20
Python  Python 2.7.4: /usr/bin/python (prefix: /usr)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "../gluon/restricted.py", line 217, in restricted  
    exec ccode in environment  
  File "../applications/app/controllers/default.py", line 103, in <module>  
  File "../gluon/globals.py", line 378, in <lambda>  
    self._caller = lambda f: f()  
  File "../gluon/globals.py", line 348, in f  
    raise e  
TypeError: not indexable
```

any ideas?

Comment: What sort of PUT/DELETE requests are you sending? Do they include the ID?

Comment: I use the same requests as the example, with the id. e.g.  

     curl -X DELETE --user user:pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/RT/default/api/entries/1.json

Comment: Is there anymore data within the HTTP 400 response? Can you catch the whole response to see if it has some payload?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST    

Set-Cookie:  ..; Path=/    
Content-Length: 17  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 06:42:37 GMT
Server: Rocket 1.2.6 Python/2.7.4  
Connection: keep-alive  

invalid arguments`

Comment: wierd, I restarted the server and now PUT works, but DELETE gives me `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> not indexable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging I found out the problem is caused by the `vars` parsing function, which throws an exception. I added the following code in `globals.py` at `def restful(self)` :

```
if rest_action.func_name == 'DELETE':
    return  rest_action(*_self.args)
```

This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Implementing RESTful service in web2py

```
@request.restful()
def API():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    def GET(*args, **vars):
        return dict()
    def POST(*args, **vars):
        return dict()
    def DELETE(*args, **vars):
        return dict()
    def PUT(*args, **vars):
        return dict()
    return locals()
```